# Python: Running a scrapy spider indefinitely to monitor page changes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to check the price and availability of certain clothing products I'm interested in.

The program itself works as intended, but now I'm not sure how to get it to continually loop to work as a page monitor.  I plan on renting out a server to have it run there indefinitely and if there's a change in the availability or price, it will notify me via slack.  I use only one spider, so my code looks something like this:

```
class MonitorSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'page_monitor'
    sitemap_urls = [
    'https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml'
    'https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml'
    'https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml'
    ]

    # Using the sitemap rules so time won't be wasted following links I don't care about
    sitemap_rules =[('keyword', 'parse')]

    def parse(self, response):
        magically get price and availability
```

Also, if anyone could settle a debate I had with a friend earlier that'd be pretty helpful too.  He thinks that beautiful soup would run faster for a project like this, but I think scrapy is the better option because the problem I've run into with scrapy in the past is that it's usually TOO fast and can get you temporarily IP banned from the site (I plan on incorporating proxies to get around this).  I know I could make a script that replicates this one using beautiful soup and just test the two, but I'd rather not do so if it's not necessary.

Speed is very important concerning this program. I want to be notified if it's available ASAP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to scrape the same url - you should yield it one more time:

```
def parse(self, response):
    magically get price and availability
    yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

Answer for you and your friend debate is in [Scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#faq-scrapy-bs-cmp):

> BeautifulSoup and lxml are libraries for parsing HTML and XML. Scrapy
>   is an application framework for writing web spiders that crawl web
>   sites and extract data from them.
>
> Scrapy provides a built-in mechanism for extracting data (called
>   selectors) but you can easily use BeautifulSoup (or lxml) instead, if
>   you feel more comfortable working with them. After all, they’re just
>   parsing libraries which can be imported and used from any Python code.
>
> In other words, comparing BeautifulSoup (or lxml) to Scrapy is like
>   comparing jinja2 to Django.

Comment: Wow, honestly don't know how I didn't think to just yield the function a second time. Also, jinja2 is supposed to be faster than django so it's saying beautifulsoup is faster than scrapy?  Scrapy can run multiple requests at the same time while bs4 can't.  You'd think it would be much faster at crawling sitemaps for product links